Vuetify3 VNavigationDrawer partly hide after upgrade to 3.6.0
Vue Version: 3.4.21
Vuetify Version: 3.5.8
I want to use the VEmptyState component, but it is only provided in Vuetify version 3.6.0 and later. After upgrading my project's version to 3.6.0, I found that some of the VNavigationDrawer components in my project, which were previously controlled by buttons to show and hide, are now permanently displayed on the screen and only half-visible. On the playground i have wrote a demo and if you switch vuetify version to 3.5.8 then it can run normally.
Playground address:
https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#...
I hope the VNavigationDrawer component can be controlled by a button to show and hide, just like in the old version (3.5.8).

You have set temporary prop which applys alternate styles for mobile devices for VNavigationDrawer, VNavigationDrawer will open with an overlay that has a very high z-index and prevents you from interacting with other UI beneath the navigation drawer. You can only close VNavigationDrawer with a button inside the drawer or remove the persistent prop from VNavigationDrawer.
VNavigationDrawer are permanently displayed because you add a class w-33 on it, just remove it. If you want to set the width of the drawer, please via its prop https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#props-width
playground: https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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
